# Force clients to reload my bundle.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm using React and Webpack to create a completely front-end application. I just made some changes to my build. Now my concern is that my users won't get to use the latest bundle but the cached bundle by their browsers. How can I get them to load the latest bundle?

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to add a code for loading assets forcefully in client browser as this will result in the slow rendering of application.

The task you want to achieve can be done by adding a new query parameter **version** on your script tag and change that version whenever you want to load new code.

something like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js?REVISION"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick. Try adding a query parameter in the script url.

For example:
`http://example.com/scripts/bundle.js?something=something`

I think that prevents browsers from caching the file.